# Iterating through Dictionary/List realtime every few ms

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a simple code like this:

```
public void OnGUI
{
if (this.myDict.Count > 0)
 {
   //blah
   foreach (GameObject gameObject in new List<GameObject>(this.myDict.Keys))
   { 
     //keep stuff up to date
   }
 }
}
```

onGUI is Unity's default method that updates every frame (really does not matter how often in this case when we iterate at the level of every frame or slightly lower, stop moving goalposts). And I NEED to keep data up-to-date as often, it is realtime list, but at the same time I NEED to be able to **modify** Dictionary (add/remove). Now, some random people told me that this foreach which allocates (?) new List every time is a massive memory leak and bad, but when asked why and how they weren't able to explain. I did some googling but result were inconclusive, I found some examples marked as "efficient" which used similar approach.

I'm greatly confused - is there a better way? Shall I define List as a global variable and use it as a temporal bin instead of defining local one each time? Would it matter though?

Comment: "onGUI is Unity's default method that updates every frame" - no, noooooo it is not, according to [their documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html). Use `Update()` if you're trying to execute something once every frame.

Comment: No more alloc with `foreach` loop. By the way, it is `OnGUI` not `onGUI` and the spelling counts here. Anyways, avoid `onGUI`. Use Unity's new UI system if that's the reason you are using it. If not use the `Update` function like serlite said.

Comment: @Programmer How about `in new List<GameObject>(...` which is the real OP question the way I understand it, not `foreach` itself.

Comment: @IvanStoev My duplicate focused on *"Now, some random people told me that this foreach which allocates (?)"*..... `new List<GameObject>(` **should** allocate memory not because of the `foreach` loop but because OP is creating new List each time with the `new` keyword.

Comment: You can reopen this  question if you think it deserves an answer. I really don't think so though.

Comment: I'm failing to see how any of this related to my question.

Comment: @Digika You're right - this doesn't seem to be related to performance of `foreach`. However, could you elaborate why you're creating a new list, rather than just doing `foreach (GameObject gameObject in this.myDict.Keys)` ?

Comment: From your edit, it is the oppisite problem, OnGui gets called ***multiple times*** per frame. Honestly if you just changed your question to `void Update()` people would stop complaining.

Comment: @Rob because I need to edit dictionary content but I can't do that while iterating through it so I iterate through list of keys instead.